# Create a StreamReader/FileStream at the exact same time by two instances, throws exception File is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, file-io

I am reading a text file in a network location, based on FileWatcher events. I have two instances of the same program reading the file, when the instance 1 and 2 reads the file at the exact same seconds & milliseconds I am getting an exception saying File is being used by another process. When there is a few milliseconds difference between instance 1 and 2, this lock error is not coming.

**Things which I have tried**
1. Tried to use FileShare.ReadWrite parameter, still the issue occurs.

2. Tried to make some delay between instance 1 and 2, but at sometime, issue occurs.
3. Tried to use using statement in order to close FileStream objects, still the issue occurs.

Any thoughts/suggestions to avoid this issue.

**Code Snippets**

```
StreamReader sr = null;
FileStream fs = null;
try 
{
    fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    while (sr.Peek() != -1)
    {
     // Does only read operations no write.
    }
    sr.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    try
    {
        if (sr != null)
            sr.Close();
        if (fs != null)
            fs.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception innerException)
    {

    }  
 }
```

Comment: I would suggest create single route which reads the files and puts the content on a queue along with the filename as a header. Then you can have parallel processing on that queue

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to use some kind of retry strategy and wrap your code in a `try/catch`. You can also put your `fs` and `sr` declarations in `using` statements so you don't have to worry about calling `Close` on them:

```
int retries = 3;

while (retries > 0)
{
    try
    {
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(FileName))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            while (sr.Peek() != -1)
            {
                // Does only read operations no write.
            }
        }

        break; // Exit the while loop if successful
    }
    catch
    {
        // Decrement our retry count and wait a bit if we're not done
        if (--retries > 0) Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone can give you a cleaner answer, but if reading the file is critical, then I'd probably just throw it in a try/catch block, and wait a few milliseconds if it fails due to the lock before trying again.

Unfortunately, in larger systems with lots of disk activity, that approach may be detrimental to performance, but in a smaller system, it should work fine.